# r - Having trouble applying a function to a vector

Tags: r

Still pretty new to R, so I'm not sure what I'm doing`wrong. I'm trying to apply this function to a vector in order to calculate % residual based on a starting value:

```
residual <- function(vec, offset, lngth){

 denom <- 1
 res_vec <- NULL
 for (i in 1:lngth){    

     if(i == 1 | i %% (offset) != 0)
{
         x <- vec[i] * 100/vec[denom]
         res_vec <- append(res_vec, x)
}

     else
{
         denom <- denom + offset
         x <- vec[i] * 100/vec[denom]
         res_vec <- append(res_vec, x)
}

}

res_vec
}
```

I'm using sapply. For example, if my vector is:

```
dv <- c(88, 84, 80, 90, 88, 85)
```

And I use sapply

```
x <- sapply(dv, residual, offset = 3, lngth = 6)
```

I'd like to get this vector:

```
100, 95, 91, 100, 98, 94
```

But instead I'm either getting this:

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]  100  100  100  100  100  100
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Is there something wrong with my function, or am I doing something wrong when trying to call it? I've gotten it to work fine in C++.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use an apply function in this case. You should be able to just input your vector into your custom function:

```
residual(vec = dv,  offset = 3, lngth = 6)
```

However, this doesn't seem to give your desired output, so I think there may be something off with the function you've written.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to cut a vector into pieces of `offset` elements each and to divide the elements of each piece by the first element of each piece. Then the pieces are appended again.

There are two tasks here:

1. Grouping the elements of the vector
2. Calculating the result for each group

One approach in base R is the `ave()` function:

```
dv <- c(88, 84, 80, 90, 88, 85)
offset <- 3L
ave(dv, cumsum(seq_along(dv) %% offset == 1L), 
    FUN = function(x) round(100 * x / x[1]))
```

which returns

> ```
> [1] 100  95  91 100  98  94
> ```

as expected.

The expression

```
cumsum(seq_along(dv) %% offset == 1L)
```

does the grouping

> ```
> [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
> ```

Alternatively, we can use `rep()`

```
rep(seq_along(dv), each = offset, length.out = length(dv))
```